How to print only the matched (non‐empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a SAME output line?
From man grep:
-o, --only-matching
  Print only the matched (non‐empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

A simple question: how to print only the matched (non‐empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a same output line?

Not sure it is possible. Are you open to a Perl one-liner?

@Toto Yes, I'm open to Perl one-liner. FYI: I've solved my problem with | awk 'ORS=NR%4?FS:RS'. Here is the full command in my case: cat log.txt | grep -P '\[0x[a-fA-F0-9]+\]' --text -o | awk 'ORS=NR%4?FS:RS'. It searches for hex numbers (4 numbers per each line) and prints them on the same line (4 numbers per each line). Note: I couldn't figure out how to do that with pure with pure grep OR with grep -o followed by column -x.

Here is a way to do the job with a Perl one-liner:
~/dev/perl$ cat file1
blah foo blah bar blah foo
blah bar blah bar
bar blah bar foo foo blah bar foo
~/dev/perl$ perl -ane '@l=$_=~/(foo)/g;print"@l\n"if@l' file1
foo foo
foo foo foo
~/dev/perl$

Explanation:
perl -ane '             # invoque Perl interpreter
@l=$_=~/(foo)/g;        # match all "foo" (here insert the string to match) on a line and store in an array (@l)
print"@l\n"if@l         # print the array if not empty
' 
file1                   # file to be processed


Another possible solution by using grep and awk:
└─$ cat file1
blah foo blah bar blah foo
blah bar blah bar
bar blah bar foo foo blah bar foo  

─$ grep -on foo file | awk -F ":" 's != $1 || NR==1{s=$1;if(p){print p};p=$2;next};{p=p" "$2;}END{print p}'
foo foo
foo foo foo

Which is:
grep -on foo file --> match the pattern foo and prefix each line of output with the 1‐based line number within its input file. Same line number is repeated in case of more than one match, eg:
└─$ grep -on foo file 
1:foo
1:foo
3:foo
3:foo
3:foo

awk:

-F ":" --> consider colon as separator to parse fields
s != $1 || NR==1 --> check if variable s is different from the value
of the first field OR the line under analysis is the first one. When true, do the following:

s=$1; --> variable s take the value of first field (line number)
if(p){print p}; --> if variable p is valued, print it
p=$2; --> variable p take the value of second field (matched pattern)
next --> go to the next iteration, and start re-evaluating the condition s != $1 || NR==1 on the next line


{p=p" "$2;} --> if the condition at step 2 is false (when line number is the same of the line before: multiple match on the same line) then the variable p take the value of itself concatenated to the second field (matched pattern) of the line under analysis (with a space between them).
END{print p} --> at the end, when all lines have been analyzed, print the last value saved in variable p.

Hence, in the case above:
line 1 --> 1:foo is analyzed: the condition is true because NR==1. s take the vale 1, p is not valued and therefore not printed, p take the value foo, go on analyzing the 2nd line.
line 2 --> 1:foo is analyzed: the condition is false because s==$1 (the first field of this line is = 1 and the variable s is 1 from the previous step) and NR==2 (we are on the 2nd line). Hence we proceed by doing {p=p" "$2;}, whereby the variable p take itself value + " " + $2 (which is foo), becoming foo foo
line 3 --> 3:foo is analyzed: the condition is true because s!=$1 (indeed s is 1 and the first field of the third line is 3). s take the vale 3, p is valued (foo foo from the previous step) and therefore is printed, p take the value foo, go on analyzing the 4th line
line 4 --> 3:foo is analyzed: the condition is false because s==$1 (the first field of this line is = 3 and the variable s is 3 from the previous step) and NR==4 (we are on the 4th line). Hence we proceed by doing {p=p" "$2;}, whereby the variable p take itself value + " " + $2 (which is foo), becoming foo foo
line 5 --> 3:foo is analyzed: the condition is false because s==$1 (the first field of this line is = 3 and the variable s is 3 from step 3) and NR==5 (we are on the 5th line). Hence we proceed by doing {p=p" "$2;}, whereby the variable p take itself value (which is 'foo foo' from the previous step) + " " + $2 (which is foo), becoming foo foo foo
END --> there are no more lines to analyze. So the part after END is executed, {print p}, and the variable p (which now contains foo foo foo, from the previous step) is printed.
Final output:
foo foo
foo foo foo

